# Ogrr market size

Tags: exchanges, trading, ecommerce, forum

I've heard that [Ogrr] (http://ogrr.com/) has provided Bitcoin as its internal unit of trading. Could someone who knows the forum well provide us with information about:

1. How large is the transaction volume every day?
2. How do members deposit/withdraw BTC to their accounts in the forum?
3. How much is the fee?
4. Do you think this forum will help raising the price of Bitcoin?

I've always been interested in implementing a virtual currency in a forum. I am curious about what forum software does Ogrr use so that they can quickly convert mBTC to USD.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Ogrr. But what makes you think it can (or should) convert mBTC to USD? One of the points of using Bitcoin for this is that it's a real global currency, it's not internal to the forum and thus needn't be converted to anything as far as the forum is concerned.

Comment: I've taken another look and, in case you meant conversion of displayed prices (as described in https://ogrr.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=479), I don't know about the implementation details but in principle it just involves polling an exchange for ticker data and doing some arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: You should drop the 4th question as that is just a matter of personal opinion and not suitable for an SE site.

Comment: There was a bitcoin-powered service like Digg / Reddit that allowed posts and replies so it was kind of like forum software -- it was called Witcoin.  It was really a neat idea.  It didn't gain much traction though -- for various reasons.  http://CoinSmack.com is along the same lines as Witcoin, but no comments / replies.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, but for the 4th questions, I think we need more opinions. And I don't see why it's not suitable for an SE site.

Comment: @StephenGornick, I went to Witcoin and found it went down sadly. I also vist CoinSmack.com but it's not really seems like a forum but a advertising site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know what the transaction volume is - only the site owner would be able to give you that information. As far as your other questions:

> How do members deposit/withdraw BTC to their accounts in the forum?

Same as you generally deposit/withdraw btc from any site. You go to your account, click the 'deposit' or 'withdraw' button, and it either gives you the address to send btc to to fill up your account, or it tells you to input the address to which you would like to withdraw.

> How much is the fee?

I understand there's currently no fee being charged by the site.

> Do you think this forum will help raising the price of Bitcoin?

Any venture that results in more people using bitcoin will, ceteris paribus, raise the price of bitcoin.

Hope that was helpful. :)

Comment: See, like right there is the reason every forum software, including right here -- Stack Exchange, should have a system for giving credit of some sort.   Thanks to nanotube I now know what ceteris paribus means ("all other things being equal").  I'ld like to give him a few cents as a tip to express my appreciation for expanding my vocabulary.  Hitting upvote/+1 on his answer really doesn't let me express my appreciation like maybe a monetary tip would.